# does minimality condition imply normal p-sylow subgroup >

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Assume that $G$ is a finite group, and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$.

Let $\cal C=\cal C(H)$ be the following condition :
"$H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $|G/H|$ is coprime to $p$".

Question : if $G$ is such that there exists a minimal subgroup $H$ with respect 
to condition $\cal C$, must $H$ be a p-sylow subgroup of $G$ ?

Equivalently, if $G$ is such that for any two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ satisfying condition $\cal C$, $H_1\cap H_2$ also satisfies $\cal C$. Must $G$ contain a unique p-Sylow subgroup ?

Comment: Do you mean $|G/H|$ is coprime to $p$?

Comment: Yes thank you Arthur.

Comment: It is true for every finite group $G$ that there is a minimal subgroup satisfying that condition. It's called $O^{p'}(G)$. And in a finite nonabelian simple group that subgroup would be the whole of $G$.

Comment: To expand what Derek says, the minimal such subgroup $H$ is just the group generated by all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ ( or, equivalently, the subgroup generated by all elements of $p$-power order in $G$).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a name for that group other that the symbol $O^{p'}(G)$? Where can I find doc on that subject?

Comment: @MikeTeX: Derek and Geoff did not state it explicitly: $O^{p'}(G)$ exists for all finite groups $G$, **no matter** if it has a unique $p$-Sylow or not. You should find it mentioned in most text books about finite groups like Aschbacher or Kurzweil/Stellmacher. In the latter book it's called the $p'$-residue.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I think the answers of Derek and Geoff are OK, since they have stated this subgroup exists for every finite group $G$.

Comment: I have spent 1 hour to try to find information online. What I need is a name for that group.

Comment: @Geoff : Where can I find a proof that $O^{p'}(G)$ is the subgroup generated by the elements of $p$-power order ?

Comment: You possibly won't find it online explicitly. It is a matter of thought really. If $H \lhd G$ with $G/H$ of order prime to $p,$ then for any $p$-element $x \in H$, the order of $Hx$ in $G/H$ is still still of order a power of $p,$ but also divides $[G:H],$ which is prime to $p.$ Hence $Hx$ has order $1$, ie $x \in H.$ On the other hand, the group generated by all elements of $p$-power order is normal, and the factor group has to be of order prime to $p$.