# Properties of p-residue group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Related thread (definition of $O^{p'}(G)$) :
[does minimality condition imply normal p-sylow subgroup >](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204109/does-minimality-condition-imply-normal-p-sylow-subgroup?noredirect=1#comment2455956_1204109)

Assume that $G$ is a finite group, and that $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$. 
Let $\Omega = O^{p'}(G)$, and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

Are the following true :
1) $O^{p'}(H) = \Omega \cap H$ ;
2) assuming furthermore $H$ normal in $G$, $O^{p'}(G/H) = \Omega / (\Omega \cap H)$.

N.B: In case one or both of these properties are true, I would especially enjoy some reference.

Comment: If you looked at a few small examples, you would soon find that 1) is false in general. For 2), it would be more accurate to write $O^{p'}(G/H) = \Omega H/H$, which is not hard to prove.

Comment: Well, group theory is not particularly my domain, so ... may someone add something more explicit?

Comment: OK. I think I got it for the 2d question : it suffices to prove that an homomorphism from $G$ to another group $G'$ transports $O^{p'}(G)$ to $O^{p'}(G')$, which is indeed not difficult. What about a small example for the 1st question ?